# Page numbers with CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, printing

An interesting use case has popped up for us, we are requiring that when we print a website  the printed copy will have a page header and footer, and inside the footer the page number.

Anyone got any idea how to achieve this?

Note: Browser version can be the latest of anything, clients are other web developers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Browser Support for CSS Page Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15797161/browser-support-for-css-page-numbers)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Depending on your required browser support.

```
@page {
  @bottom-right {
    content: counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
  }
}
```

Further reading:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/
- http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/2010/08/20/add-page-number-using-page-property-of-css/
- http://www.princexml.com/doc/6.0/page-numbers/

Comment: Thanks mate, will give that a go :) Any idea about browser support?

Comment: @balupton Not sure, give Quirks Mode a look into :)

Comment: I was looking more for the `@page` and `@bottom-right` pieces. I've used content and counter but haven't been able to get this to actually display anywhere, and can't find on caniuse or elsewhere where it should work for sure.

Comment: Did anyone actually get the @page content displayed in an existing browser in the meantime? It looks like it just isn't implemented anywhere...

Comment: Not @page, but CSS page numbers in Firefox can work using display:table and counters - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15797161/browser-support-for-css-page-numbers/16651296#16651296

Comment: @alex whats the replacement for `@page` margin boxes then now? It would really help to be able to print page numbers in IE11

Comment: These don't work in any major browsers as of now. :)

Comment: Any chance that this is working on major browsers now?