# get printed page number of an element

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing, tableofcontents

I'm working on a project that is involving converting PDF handbooks to html.  I am trying to retain the value of a PDF when printed, while giving them a better ui on devices which aren't bound by the concept of pages.  The issue that I am running into is that these handbooks have a Table of Contents with the page number of where each chapter/section begins.  When viewing on a device, that list will just be in-page anchor links, but when printing I would like to get the page number of an element (such as which page the heading for Chapter 3 is on) and add it to the table of contents, especially after applying print styles like `page-break-after:avoid;`.

As an example, I would like to know what it would take to accurately add page numbers to the following wikipedia article's table of contents when printed.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_mask

**Edit:**
My thought is to use a print stylesheet to add page numbers when printing:

```
@page {
    @bottom {
        content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages)
    }
}
```

and then use javascript to detect the print using matchMedia/onbeforeprint (http://tjvantoll.com/2012/06/15/detecting-print-requests-with-javascript/) and then grab the page number from the content, but I'm not sure how to find that dynamically added content.  Is that possible? Is there some other solution?

Comment: HTML printing will vary from browser to browser, therefore so will the page numbering. If you want realistic page numbers. you're better of sticking with the PDF.

Comment: This another question could help you:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109893/page-numbers-with-css-html

Comment: @DouglasLise, That's the easy part.  I need to know how/if I can grab those page numbers before the document is printed and insert them into a table of contents.

Comment: Sorry @mlrawlings, I got confused. But had you tried using "target-counter" CSS property? This link could help you http://alistapart.com/article/boom Inside it, find by target-count...

Comment: @DouglasLise I need to read a bit more, but at first glance that looks like what I was looking for. Thanks!