# Browser Support for CSS Page Numbers

Tags: css, printing, cross-browser, css-paged-media

So I am aware of this option: [Page numbers with CSS/HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109893/page-numbers-with-css-html/6109932).

It seems by far to be the best way to add page numbers to a print version of a page, but I can't get any variation of this to work anywhere. I have tried on my Windows 7 machine in Chrome, Firefox, and IE9. Based on some of the links it looks like this may be supported in more proprietary software like Prince XML. Is this supported by web browsers for print versions?

I have tried making just a blank html file and in the head adding this between two style tags:

```
@page {
  @bottom-right {
    content: counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
  }
}
```

I have also simplified it even to just use `content: "TEXT";` to see if I can get something to show up. Is this supported anywhere? By 'this' I'm specifically meaning the `@page` and `@bottom-right` tags, since I have gotten content to work many times.

Comment: It appears that no, paged media is not supported by chrome or firefox (and maybe not IE9 either). CSS3 was supposed to have some support for paged media, but I haven't been able to get it to work either.

Comment: That is likely the answer then. I keep finding this around in answers and tutorials but can't find any implementation that works. Guess it is another thing to remember for the future.

Comment: It is possible there are other parameters required for paged media style sheets to display.  If multiple "pages" are on a web page, how are you declaring a page?

Comment: Would a media query work? Then you could use `@media print` on an element snapped to the bottom right of the page as a workaround.

Comment: To answer the last question: no. Paged media margin boxes are not yet supported in any major browsers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28Cascading_Style_Sheets%29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This does not seem to work anymore. Appears it only worked for a short time and browser support was removed!**

Counters have to be reset before they can be used, according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Counters.

You can set your starting number to whatever, the default is 0.

Example:

```
@page {
    counter-increment: page;
    counter-reset: page 1;
    @top-right {
        content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
    }
}
```

Page media is not well supported by any major web browser, but is supported by specialized HTML to PDF generators such as Prince XML and WeasyPrint.

Comment: That is good to know, but I'm still not actually getting this to output anything. Can you provide any insight into the `@page` tag? Does this actually display for you?

Comment: Unfortunately, @page is not supported in Firefox, but supported in Chrome 2.0+, IE 8.0+, Opera 6.0+ and Safari 5.0+. `@page :first` is supported only in IE8+ and Opera 9.2+.  This is per [link](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/)  I did get the `@page` margin to work in FF but nothing else.

Comment: Also, Mozilla's documentation sates that FF19.0 offers "Basic-Support" for `@page` [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/@page) bottom of page which matches my inability to get any of the `@page` stuff to work except margin

Comment: One last reference.  There's a very detailed article "Building Books with CSS3" at A List Apart [link](http://alistapart.com/article/building-books-with-css3) by Nellie McKesson, the eBook Operations Manager at O’Reilly Media, who in the comments said "AFAIK, there’s no browser support for paged media yet" though this was June 12,2012

Comment: Thanks for the links John. I think that you have confirmed my findings as well. I guess it is time to get creative...

Comment: @John Biddle: That's for CSS3 paged media though, not CSS2.

Comment: The "page" counter is automatically reset and incremented for you in the CSS3 page module http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/#page-based-counters

Comment: This is not working for me... it is compatibile with any browsers?

Comment: There is NO support for paged media margin boxes in ANY major browsers yet. Stop providing answers based on unimplemented working drafts. Please. I'm also very curious how this got accepted because as of today this code has exactly no effect.

Comment: Please remove this answer since this is a non working situation. I've wasted a lot of time because it wasn't prefaced as tested with live browsers.

Comment: does not work with Chrome Version 49.0.2614.0 canary (64-bit) & Version 47.0.2526.106 (64-bit) as of 1/6/16

Comment: Agreed. This is theory, not a practical answer.

Comment: A working example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050939/print-page-numbers-on-pages-when-printing-html/58059786#58059786

Answer (score 17):

I've been trying to implement paged media as well and have found, according to this Wikipedia page, that there's no browser support for margin boxes as yet. No wonder it wouldn't work!

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_(Cascading_Style_Sheets)

See the table, Grammar and Rules, margin boxes section. Margin boxes are what's needed for page numbering as well as running headers and footers. Getting this implemented would save me the overhead of having to convert the printed media to PDF.

Comment: That wikipedia link doesn't work. There is no article at the target url.

Comment: The above article was last updated in 2017 and is now archived: https://web.archive.org/web/20220526233027/http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_browser_engines_(CSS_support)

Answer (score 11):

Not using @page, but I have gotten pure CSS page numbers to work in Firefox 20:

http://jsfiddle.net/okohll/QnFKZ/

To print, right click in the results frame (bottom right) and select

This Frame -> Print Frame...

The CSS is

```
#content {
    display: table;
}

#pageFooter {
    display: table-footer-group;
}

#pageFooter:after {
    counter-increment: page;
    content: counter(page);
}
```

and the HTML is

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="pageFooter">Page </div>
  multi-page content here...
</div>
```

Comment: But it's not really a page footer. If the text ends up spanning more than one page, `#pageFooter` will end up beneath where the text ends on the last page.

Comment: That's true. Not as nice as if @page worked fully. I suppose one hack could be to add spacing to the end of the last content element to push the footer down on the last page

Comment: What’s the browser support for this solution? On my Mac with Chrome, Opera, and Safari, table headers and footers only print at the beginning and end of the table. Firefox prints them on every page, but counter(page) only works the first time it displays. Does this work for you and I’m just doing something wrong?

Comment: My instincts says that this implementation of counter is related to the internal behavior of OL and has nothing to do with print/pages.

Comment: It seems to be the best workaround so far, if you don't want to buy a prince :-)
Did you ever get a non-zero value for "counter(pages)" (i.e.: the total number of pages)?

Comment: this looks nice, but does not seem to work with current chrome version.

Comment: This example is for 1 page only.
How can you increment pages with this solution ?

Answer (score 2):

Via Mozilla, ([Printing a document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Media))

This puts a header and footer on each printed page. This works well in Mozilla, but not quite so well in IE and Chrome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Print sample</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style4.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Section A</h1>
<p>This is the first section...</p>
<h1>Section B</h1>
<p>This is the second section...</p>
<div id="print-head">
  Heading for paged media
</div>
<div id="print-foot">
  Page: 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```
/*** Print sample ***/

/* defaults  for screen */
#print-head,
#print-foot {
    display: none;
}

/* print only */
@media print {

h1 {
   page-break-before: always;
   padding-top: 2em;
}

h1:first-child {
  page-break-before: avoid;
  counter-reset: page;
}

#print-head {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0pt;
    left:0pt;
    right: 0pt;

    font-size: 200%;
    text-align: center;
}

#print-foot {
   display: block;
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0pt;
   right: 0pt;

  font-size: 200%;
}

#print-foot:after {
    content: counter(page);
    counter-increment: page;
}
```

Comment: This works in Firefox, which is good. But I haven't found a way how to make it work in Chrome (53) or IE (11)

Comment: Header and footer are printed over the page's text :( Can't find out how to create blank margins on each page to print header/footer there. If I specify `top: -0.5cm`, header is moving up, but gets cut with page's margin and only partially visible. `overflow: visible` does not help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to add page numbers when printing under Chrome/Chromium, one easy solution is to use [Paged.js](https://www.pagedjs.org/).

This JS library takes your HTML/CSS and cuts it into pages, ready to print as a book, that you will preview in your browser. It makes the `@page` and most the CSS3 specifications work for Chrome.

### Solution 1 (easy) if you are OK with cutting your view into pages, ready to print

Just add their CDN in the `head` tag of your page :

```
<link href="path/to/file/interface.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

You can then add page numbers by using the automated counter `page`. Example :

HTML to put anywhere you want to display the current page number:

```
<div class="page-number"></div>
```

CSS to make the number appear in the div :

```
.page-number{
  content: counter(page)
}
```

The library also allows to easily manage page margins, footers, headers, etc.

### Solution 2 (trickier) if you want to show numbers (and page breaks) only when printing

In this case, you need to apply the Paged.js CDN only when printing the document.
One way I can think of would be to add a `print me` button that fires Javascript to :

1. add the CDN to the page
2. **and then** execute  `window.print();` to launch the printing prompt of the navigator