# How can I generate a PDF from HTML and use CSS @page numbering (via C#)?

Tags: c#, html, css, pdf

I need to generate some PDFs from HTML for the project I'm working on.  I've been using [EvoPDF](http://www.evopdf.com/) heretofore, and it's worked well but now I have a requirement for page numbering.

I *suspect* (but am waiting for their tech support to verify) that the CSS @page numbering is not supported.  This throws a minor wrench in the works as it will make the code ugly because I have to manually apply PDF elements to the page, and it breaks the wrapper I've put around EvoPDF.

I would love to be able to use the CSS @page counter method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15988367/css-page-numbers-not-working) in order to get page numbering.  Basically, I want the Chrome "Print to PDF" option called programatically.

It would be awesome if the solution had C# bindings.  Less awesome but probably ok if it was a command line call (I'm using Windows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@page is not supported in most HTML to PDF conversion engines. A lot of these are running on webkit (like [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/), [HTM2PDF](http://www.htm2pdf.co.uk), [PDFmyURL](http://PDFmyURL.com), [PDFcrowd](http://pdfcrwd.com) and what not) and none of these support @page yet.

Of course the ones that use the IE rendering engine do not support @page either.

I believe [Prince XML](http://www.princexml.com/) is the only one that fully supports @page at the moment, but it's quite expensive.

If you can live with page numbering in the footer/header however, then you can still use the webkit solutions mentioned above, because they all support the header/footer page numbering.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the header-footer numbering example?  And thanks for this very complete answer!