# Page Numbers when printing from Google Chrome

Tags: html

I've seen this answer...

```
@page {
  @bottom-left {
    content: counter(page) "/" counter(pages);
  }
}
```

many times, but it never outputs anything to the page for me, even though it's supposed to work. I've tried 'inventive' ways of getting page numbers at the bottom but I can never get it to work reliably. The count is fine, but the location is always off, so I've scrapped it.

Any reason why this CSS shouldn't be working? As stated, I'm printing with Google Chrome.

Answer (score -2):

There is an answer you could try from here... [Browser Support for CSS Page Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15797161/browser-support-for-css-page-numbers)

```
@page {
    counter-increment: page;
    counter-reset: page 1;
    @bottom-left {
        content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
    }
}
```

As it states on that answer, you need to reset a counter before using it (according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Counters)

Comment: I guess I should have specified, I've seen this as well and it simply doesn't output anything anywhere on the screen.