# Chrome Css Print "Current Page"

Tags: css

I have a document created with html that can have multiple pages. I would like to add the current pagenumber at the bottom of each page like "Page 1/x"

I have found this but it does not work in chrome.

```
@page {
    @bottom {
    content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages)
    }
}
```

Can anybody please help me out?

Comment: why this question is marked/tag in CSS? There is nothing related to ONLY css..

Comment: I think you have to use `webkit` in your css

Comment: Maybe this will help you out?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050939/print-page-numbers-on-pages-when-printing-html

Comment: from a quick research it seems it is not possible. cfr [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19305500/page-numbers-when-printing-from-google-chrome) or [that one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15797161/browser-support-for-css-page-numbers)