# Add Total Pages indicator using CSS on <thead> of printable document?

Tags: html, css, pagination

I modified [a CSS page-numbering solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15797161/browser-support-for-css-page-numbers/16651296#16651296) for my web page.

It automatically shows "Page 1", "Page 2", etc. I'd like it to show "Page 1 of 5", "Page 2 of 5", etc.

Here's [my current example code](http://jsfiddle.net/KeuwU/): ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KeuwU/show/))

```
@media print {
  thead span.page-number:after {
    counter-increment: page;
    content: "Page " counter(page) " of ?";
  }
}
```

HTML: (pardon me for using tables, rather than CSS `display: table-header-group`)

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="page-number"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        ..............................................................
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Is there any way to add the total page count in place of my `?`?

I'm only interested in the latest version of either Firefox or Chrome.

*My current solution so far was to use the server to create one element per page, but it is much more difficult to get optimal page breaking that way. The `<thead>` solution is much simpler.*

Comment: Could you create an element for each page in the website ?
So, a site with 3 pages (home,about,contact) would create an unordered list on each page with an li for each page. You could then use the counter-increment on those elements. Best i can come up with :)

This list could actually be a handy sitemap for users too :)

Comment: Actually, the web page I am working with is a printable company document. Your comment seems off topic for this question. Sorry. :)

Comment: All I've seen so far, can only give the total number of elements *after* everything is counted.

Comment: This is curious. It works on page 1, but not on the rest of the pages. http://jsfiddle.net/KeuwU/8/ http://jsfiddle.net/KeuwU/8/show/

Comment: In theory, one should be able to use a position:fixed element for the total page count. It would not be optimal, due to the alignment difficulties, it would have limited utility. I would post a sample, but [I haven't got it to behave right yet](http://fiddle.jshell.net/KeuwU/13/show/).

Answer (score -1):

You can use  counter(pages). Here is the example

```css
thead span.page-number:after {
    counter-increment: page;
    content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
}
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. Notice this is what I tried in the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KeuwU/show/) that I posted.

Answer (score -2):

Although not purely a CSS answer,with a little javascript and assuming that each new page/break point would be represented by a div/span/td or other HTML entity with a "common class name" contained in each one. You could get the total page count like this.

```
<div class="xxx"></div>
<div class="xxx"></div>
<div class="fff"></div>
<div id="footer">
<script type="application/javascript">
aaa = document.getElementsByClassName("xxx").length;
document.write(aaa);
</script>
</div>
```

In the example above, This would produce the number 2 being output to the browser at the point the script is inserted as the script counts the number of times xxx appears as a class in any element on the document.

Comment: Sorry, this is a wrong answer, because there is only one element involved. The element is repeated on each page because it is in a `<thead>`, but there's still only one element. `length` would always be `1`.