# How can I programmatically format printer documents with Python or other language?

Tags: python, printing

I am trying to replicate some old label-making software which allows for choosing label size among other things. The sizes of the labels are known by their standard measurements (2.5 inches by 1 inch, for example). I see how to detect OS and send basic print jobs. The print jobs seem to be just strings sent to the printer. If I am trying to, for example, move two inches right before printing the next portion of the job, would I just increase the whitespace in the string (does some amount of whitespace always correspond to a physical measurement when printed)? Is there some way to define portions of a page or some other way to jump around between XY coordinates on a known page size?

Answer (score 1):

I have written software in Python that print HTML pages. The advantage of HTML is a good language to print anything you like, formatting is easy, debugging can be done using any webbrowser.

Next you can use software like [PrinceXML](https://www.princexml.com)  that allows you to convert the HTML pages a printable page. via the stylesheet you a can define the size of your page.

Feel free to concept mee if you need more help.

Comment: So I could send the data to an html/css file and there I can specify things like a physical size?

Comment: Yes you can ..  PrinceXML understand the @page rule [link] (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/css_paged_media.htm) .

Comment: So I would look into the @page rule for doing this without proprietary software? Thanks

Comment: This is indeed a way, I have no experience the @page without PrinceXML. After all you will need some engine that understand the size of a page. And this is something most ebbrowser do not understand. See [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20946723/chrome-does-not-support-the-css-page