# @page css media does not work for Chrome and IE

Tags: css, printing, media

I've got some question about @page css media tag.

So I read some documentation written by w3 and Microsoft, but anyways no effect with it.

Following the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530841(v=vs.85).aspx when I use the parameters like they say, it does not work for me.

I even can't find any other example how to numerate pages in browser print media.

Can anyone help me?

**Updated**

here is my snippet for it. Margins work correctly, but counting dont.

```
@page {
    margin-top: 15mm;
    margin-bottom: 25mm;
    margin-left: 30mm;
    margin-right: 30mm;

    @bottom-center {
        content: "page " counter(page);
    }
}
```

Comment: soo... how about posting some of your code?

Comment: Never, ever use Microsoft documentation. Always use the actual spec or something from Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page

Comment: @Rob it required by client that it must work only for IE and they don't care about all other browsers. That's problem :(

Comment: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-page/#at-page-rule

Comment: @Resource-guru.com I read it, doesn't work.

Comment: As I understand here is only that browsers issue. I found where to enable this option in IE, but it still doesn't listen to CSS. It's nummerating pages by itself.

Answer (score 1):

### CSS3 Counters have to be reset before they can be used

Try This once

```
 @page {
    margin-top: 15mm;
    margin-bottom: 25mm;
    margin-left: 30mm;
    margin-right: 30mm;

    @bottom-center {
    counter-increment: page;
    counter-reset: page 1;
        content: "page " counter(page);
    }
}
```

[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15797161/browser-support-for-css-page-numbers/16651296#16651296)