# How to print page number using css

Tags: jquery, css

I want to print page number in each page when printing.

I want to acheive this with turn off browser print preview settings.

Here is my code.

```
.rptFooter {
    counter-reset: footerNum;
}

.rptFooter:after {
    counter-increment: footerNum;
    content: "Page " counter(footerNum) " of " counter(footerNum) ;
}
```

i am getting in each page

Page 1 of 1

Comment: Can you post a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Try this: [How to number print pages?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43768942/6557304)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the default base:

```
@page {
    counter-increment: page;
    counter-reset: page 1;
    @top-right {
        content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
    }
}
```

As seen here:

[Browser Support for CSS Page Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15797161/browser-support-for-css-page-numbers)

Comment: start from page 0 as default look at the link that is provided