# Not able to set page number in latest chrome browser using print css

Tags: html, css, printing

I am trying to print a invoice which goes over 2 pages and i want the page number to be displayed at the bottom while printing. It works fine on Firefox but chrome just prints page 1 in all pages. Is there any work around (alternate way to print page number)? I tried a lot of solutions but this does not work on chrome or IE. Please help

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

@page {
   size:8.27in 11.69in; 
   margin: 0.5cm; 
}



body { font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace; line-height: 1.5;
 font-size: 11pt; }
.header { position:fixed; top:0; text-align:center; width:100%; margin: 0 auto; height:100px; bottom:1em; }

.page-layout {
        page-break-after: always; position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    top:2em;   //match size of header
    left:0px;
    right:0px;       
    }         
.footer {  position:fixed; bottom:0; text-align:center; width:100%; margin:0 auto; }
.footer:after { width:100%;  margin:0 auto; text-align:center;
    counter-increment: page;
   content:"Page " counter(page);
} 
.inv-details {  }
.tstripe { border-top:2px dashed #000;} 
table {
 page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Invoice</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="css/print.css" />
</head>

<body>

<div class="header">Commercial Invoice</div>
<div class="page-layout">
<div class="footer"></div>
<table class="inv-details" width="100%">
 <tr>
     <td>Invoice Number</td>
        <td>Purpose of Shipment</td>
        <td>Curr <br /> USD</td>
        <td>Ult Dest. <br /> US </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Export Dt <br /> 8/14/2017 </td>
        <td>C.I. References </td>
        <td>Pkgs <br /> 1 <br /> OTH </td>
        <td>Bill T/C <br /> 1378-4267-0 </td>
      </tr>
</table>
<table class="tstripe" width="100%">
 <tr>
     <td width="50%">Shipper: <br />
        VENNY PERSAUD <br />
        SBC INC, <br />
        130 MATHESON BLVD, E, <br />
        UNIT 1</td>
        <td width="50%">Consignee: <br />
        Marlon Browder <br />
        Marlon Browder <br />
        320 E GILLESPIE ST 
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td width="50%">MISSISSAUGE <br />
        ON L4Z1Y6 CA (866) 330-1272 <br />
        ID / EIN: </td>
        <td width="50%">STARKVILLE <br />
        MS 39759 US (622) 617-9890 <br />
        ID / EIN:
        </td>
      </tr>
</table>
<table class="tstripe" width="100%">
 <tr>
     <td  valign="top" width="50%">
         Broker <br />
            FedEx Ground's Broker
        </td>
        <td>
         Importer <br />
            VENNY PERSAUD <br />
            SBC INC, <br />
            130 MATHESON BLVD, E, <br />
            UNIT 1 <br />
            MISSISSAUGA <br />
            ON L4Z1Y6 CA (866) 330 - 1272 <br />
            ID / EIN: <br />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- Item 1 -->
<table class="tstripe" width="100%">
 <tr>
     <td>Part Nbr:</td>
        <td>Marks / Nbrs: </td>
        <td>Cntry MFG: US </td>
        <td> Net Wgt: 0.00 lbs</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table width="100%">
 <tr>
     <td>HS Code: 9503.90 </td>
        <td>Unit Qty: 1.00 PCS </td>
        <td>Unit Value: 5.600000</td>
        <td>Commodity Value: 5.60 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="4">
         Desc: Latex Ballon
        </td>
      </tr>
</table>
<!-- Item 2 -->
<table class="tstripe" width="100%">
 <tr>
     <td>Part Nbr:</td>
        <td>Marks / Nbrs: </td>
        <td>Cntry MFG: US </td>
        <td> Net Wgt: 0.00 lbs</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table width="100%">
 <tr>
     <td>HS Code: 9503.90 </td>
        <td>Unit Qty: 1.00 PCS </td>
        <td>Unit Value: 5.600000</td>
        <td>Commodity Value: 5.60 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="4">
         Desc: Foil Ballon
        </td>
      </tr>
</table>

<table class="tstripe" width="100%">
 <tr>
     <td>Part Nbr:</td>
        <td>Marks / Nbrs: </td>
        <td>Cntry MFG: US </td>
        <td> Net Wgt: 0.00 lbs</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table width="100%">
 <tr>
     <td>HS Code: 9503.90 </td>
        <td>Unit Qty: 1.00 PCS </td>
        <td>Unit Value: 5.600000</td>
        <td>Commodity Value: 5.60 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="4">
         Desc: Foil Ballon
        </td>
      </tr>
</table>

<table class="tstripe" width="100%">
 <tr>
     <td>Part Nbr:</td>
        <td>Marks / Nbrs: </td>
        <td>Cntry MFG: US </td>
        <td> Net Wgt: 0.00 lbs</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table width="100%">
 <tr>
     <td>HS Code: 9503.90 </td>
        <td>Unit Qty: 1.00 PCS </td>
        <td>Unit Value: 5.600000</td>
        <td>Commodity Value: 5.60 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="4">
         Desc: Foil Ballon
        </td>
      </tr>
</table>

<table class="tstripe" width="100%">
 <tr>
     <td>Part Nbr:</td>
        <td>Marks / Nbrs: </td>
        <td>Cntry MFG: US </td>
        <td> Net Wgt: 0.00 lbs</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table width="100%">
 <tr>
     <td>HS Code: 9503.90 </td>
        <td>Unit Qty: 1.00 PCS </td>
        <td>Unit Value: 5.600000</td>
        <td>Commodity Value: 5.60 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="4">
         Desc: Foil Ballon
        </td>
      </tr>
</table>

<table class="tstripe" width="100%">
 <tr>
     <td>Part Nbr:</td>
        <td>Marks / Nbrs: </td>
        <td>Cntry MFG: US </td>
        <td> Net Wgt: 0.00 lbs</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table width="100%">
 <tr>
     <td>HS Code: 9503.90 </td>
        <td>Unit Qty: 1.00 PCS </td>
        <td>Unit Value: 5.600000</td>
        <td>Commodity Value: 5.60 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="4">
         Desc: Foil Ballon
        </td>
      </tr>
</table>



<!-- Total -->
<table class="tstripe" width="100%"  style="margin-top:30px;">
 <tr>
     <td align="right">Total Shipment Weight::</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td align="right">Total Commodity </td>
        <td align="right">29.12</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="right" colspan="3">Terms of Sale:</td>
        <td align="right">FCA</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td align="right"  colspan="3">Freight:</td>
        <td align="right">0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td align="right"  colspan="3">Insurance:</td>
        <td align="right">0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td align="right"  colspan="3">Others:</td>
  <td align="right">0.00</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td align="right"  colspan="3">Total Invoice Value:</td>
        <td align="right">29.12</td>
       </tr>         
</table>

<table>
<tr><td> Comments</td></tr>
<tr><td>1)  </td></tr>
<tr><td>2) </td></tr>
<tr><td>3) </td></tr>
<tr>
 <td>Tracking Numbers: 738443302589 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>I declare all information in this invoice to be true and correct. </td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
 <td>Signature of shipper: VENNY PERSAUD <span style="float:right;">8/14/2017</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this in chrome using jquery somehow.

```js
var bottom = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("table:nth-child(9n)").each(function() {
    bottom -= 5;
    botString = bottom.toString();
    var $counter = $('.footer.first').clone().removeClass('first');
    $counter.css("bottom", botString + "vh");
    ($counter).insertBefore('.insert');
  });
});
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

@page {
   size:8.27in 11.69in; 
   margin: 0.5cm; 
}



body { font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace; line-height: 1.5;
 font-size: 11pt; }
.header { position:fixed; top:0; text-align:center; width:100%; margin: 0 auto; height:100px; bottom:1em; }

.page-layout {
        page-break-after: always; position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    top:2em;   //match size of header
    left:0px;
    right:0px;       
     
    }    
    body { counter-reset: page; }     
.footer {text-align:center; width:100%; margin:0 auto; position: absolute; }
.footer::after { top: 95vh; position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap; 
    z-index: 20px; width:100%;  margin:0 auto; text-align:center;
    counter-increment: page;
   content:"Page " counter(page);
} 
.inv-details {  }
.tstripe { border-top:2px dashed #000;} 
table {
 page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="footer first"></div>
 <div class="insert"></div>
<div class="header">Commercial Invoice</div>
<div class="page-layout">

<table class="inv-details" width="100%">
 <tr>
     <td>Invoice Number</td>
        <td>Purpose of Shipment</td>
        <td>Curr <br /> USD</td>
        <td>Ult Dest. <br /> US </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Export Dt <br /> 8/14/2017 </td>
        <td>C.I. References </td>
        <td>Pkgs <br /> 1 <br /> OTH </td>
        <td>Bill T/C <br /> 1378-4267-0 </td>
      </tr>
</table>
<table class="tstripe" width="100%">
 <tr>
     <td width="50%">Shipper: <br />
        VENNY PERSAUD <br />
        SBC INC, <br />
        130 MATHESON BLVD, E, <br />
        UNIT 1</td>
        <td width="50%">Consignee: <br />
        Marlon Browder <br />
        Marlon Browder <br />
        320 E GILLESPIE ST 
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td width="50%">MISSISSAUGE <br />
        ON L4Z1Y6 CA (866) 330-1272 <br />
        ID / EIN: </td>
        <td width="50%">STARKVILLE <br />
        MS 39759 US (622) 617-9890 <br />
        ID / EIN:
        </td>
      </tr>
</table>
<table class="tstripe" width="100%">
 <tr>
     <td  valign="top" width="50%">
         Broker <br />
            FedEx Ground's Broker
        </td>
        <td>
         Importer <br />
            VENNY PERSAUD <br />
            SBC INC, <br />
            130 MATHESON BLVD, E, <br />
            UNIT 1 <br />
            MISSISSAUGA <br />
            ON L4Z1Y6 CA (866) 330 - 1272 <br />
            ID / EIN: <br />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>


<!-- Item 1 -->
<table class="tstripe" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>Part Nbr:</td>
        <td>Marks / Nbrs: </td>
        <td>Cntry MFG: US </td>
        <td> Net Wgt: 0.00 lbs</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>HS Code: 9503.90 </td>
        <td>Unit Qty: 1.00 PCS </td>
        <td>Unit Value: 5.600000</td>
        <td>Commodity Value: 5.60 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            Desc: Foil Ballon
        </td>
      </tr>
</table>


<!-- Item 2 -->
<table class="tstripe" width="100%">
 <tr>
     <td>Part Nbr:</td>
        <td>Marks / Nbrs: </td>
        <td>Cntry MFG: US </td>
        <td> Net Wgt: 0.00 lbs</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table width="100%">
 <tr>
     <td>HS Code: 9503.90 </td>
        <td>Unit Qty: 1.00 PCS </td>
        <td>Unit Value: 5.600000</td>
        <td>Commodity Value: 5.60 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="4">
         Desc: Foil Ballon
        </td>
      </tr>
</table>

<!-- Item 3 -->
<table class="tstripe" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>Part Nbr:</td>
        <td>Marks / Nbrs: </td>
        <td>Cntry MFG: US </td>
        <td> Net Wgt: 0.00 lbs</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>HS Code: 9503.90 </td>
        <td>Unit Qty: 1.00 PCS </td>
        <td>Unit Value: 5.600000</td>
        <td>Commodity Value: 5.60 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            Desc: Foil Ballon
        </td>
      </tr>
</table>

<!-- Item 4 -->
<table class="tstripe" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>Part Nbr:</td>
        <td>Marks / Nbrs: </td>
        <td>Cntry MFG: US </td>
        <td> Net Wgt: 0.00 lbs</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>HS Code: 9503.90 </td>
        <td>Unit Qty: 1.00 PCS </td>
        <td>Unit Value: 5.600000</td>
        <td>Commodity Value: 5.60 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            Desc: Foil Ballon
        </td>
      </tr>
</table>

<!-- Item 5 -->
<table class="tstripe" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>Part Nbr:</td>
        <td>Marks / Nbrs: </td>
        <td>Cntry MFG: US </td>
        <td> Net Wgt: 0.00 lbs</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>HS Code: 9503.90 </td>
        <td>Unit Qty: 1.00 PCS </td>
        <td>Unit Value: 5.600000</td>
        <td>Commodity Value: 5.60 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            Desc: Foil Ballon
        </td>
      </tr>
</table>


<!-- Item 6 -->
<table class="tstripe" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>Part Nbr:</td>
        <td>Marks / Nbrs: </td>
        <td>Cntry MFG: US </td>
        <td> Net Wgt: 0.00 lbs</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>HS Code: 9503.90 </td>
        <td>Unit Qty: 1.00 PCS </td>
        <td>Unit Value: 5.600000</td>
        <td>Commodity Value: 5.60 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            Desc: Foil Ballon
        </td>
      </tr>
</table>

<!-- Total -->
<table class="tstripe" width="100%"  style="margin-top:30px;">
 <tr>
     <td align="right">Total Shipment Weight::</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td align="right">Total Commodity </td>
        <td align="right">29.12</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="right" colspan="3">Terms of Sale:</td>
        <td align="right">FCA</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td align="right"  colspan="3">Freight:</td>
        <td align="right">0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td align="right"  colspan="3">Insurance:</td>
        <td align="right">0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td align="right"  colspan="3">Others:</td>
  <td align="right">0.00</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td align="right"  colspan="3">Total Invoice Value:</td>
        <td align="right">29.12</td>
       </tr>         
</table>

<table>
<tr><td> Comments</td></tr>
<tr><td>1)  </td></tr>
<tr><td>2) </td></tr>
<tr><td>3) </td></tr>
<tr>
 <td>Tracking Numbers: 738443302589 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>I declare all information in this invoice to be true and correct. </td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
 <td>Signature of shipper: VENNY PERSAUD <span style="float:right;">8/14/2017</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```