# How to print page number in Chrome and Opera

Tags: html, css, printing, opera

I have a web app. I'm using Chrome and Opera on that app.
I want to put the page number in the print page preview in a specific `td` form like this:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>thead data</td>
        <td>thead data</td>
        <td>page number of pages numbers</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>tbody data</td>
        <td>tbody data</td>
        <td>tbody data</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

In Firefox I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36229180/4588796) on StackOverflow.
It worked only in Firefox.
But my problem is that I want it in Chrome and Opera.
I've tried many things but nothing works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To print page numbers you've to set Chrome and Opera print settings.

Click **Ctrl + P** and a popup will appear. Click on **More Settings** button and check the **Header & Footer** and it will show the page numbers.

Comment: the print settings in opera and chrome not in specific div like what i want

Comment: The trick is, how do you make it show page numbers without the URL?