# How to put page number in bottom when using counter property

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I create page number that using `counter` property in css am trying to put it in the end of the page and I need to use *pure css*

this is my CSS:

```
@media print {
        table.break {
            page-break-after: left;
        }
        body {
            counter-reset: table;
        }
        table::after {
            counter-increment: table;
            content: "page"" "counter(table);
        }
        .no-print, .no-print * {
            display: none;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CSS
@page {
    @bottom {
    content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages)
    }
}
```

This rule will generate page footers such as "Page 1 of 89".

For More Information

http://www.princexml.com/doc/page-numbers/

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6109932/4513879

Comment: I tried this before put it's return an error "content is not valid value for the bottom property "