# Couldn't insert a text into sub-selectors of @page selector

Tags: html, css, printing, counter

I need to write a bunch of formatted text, which is uncomfortable to do *(at least to me)* with Office apps, so I do this with Markdown + CSS. I stuck with the problem that I couldn't set *page counters*. E.g. [this answer tells](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6109932/2388257) that I have to use a sub-selector `@bottom-right` of the `@page` to paste a number, like

```
@page {
  @bottom-right {
    content: counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
  }
}
```

*[@page selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/#syntax-page-selector) configures formatting for one prints a page.* Unfortunately the example didn't work for me. In fact, I couldn't insert any text using the `content:` function.

A minimal *(non-)* working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><title>test</title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
        <style>
        h1 {
            counter-reset: subsection;
            page-break-after: always;
        }
        @page{
            @top-left {
                content: "Hello";
            }
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Section 1</h1>
        <h1>Section 2</h1>
        <h1>Section 3</h1>
        <h1>Section 4</h1>
        <h1>Section 5</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here you see five headers that being shown as five separate pages when you ask a browser to *print* it. Besides, accordingly to the `@page` rule, you should see somewhere in top-left corner of every page a word «Hello». Do you? I tested in Firefox and Chrome, and no matter what corner I choose, I never see the text there.

I also tried *(although it supposed to be unneeded for the @page)* to wrap it into `@media print{…}`, that changed nothing.

*Note:* when testing, don't be confused by the page counters that browsers tends to insert on its own.

Comment: Nope. According to a comment on the linked answer, it doesn't work. See [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28Cascading_Style_Sheets%29#Grammar_and_rules). Another comment says it works on IE8, but I haven't gotten it to work on IE8 either.

Comment: @MrLister hm… That's interesting, so, the problem is a missing support… But in fact I saw at least a few articles about designing a book with this CSS feature. [E.g. this one](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/01/07/designing-for-print-with-css/). I am curious how would they forced it to work then.