# Display page numbers using @page directive

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm having trouble getting the @page directive to work in my CSS.  Using Google Chrome to test; VS2015, MVC5 to develop
Here's what's in my CSS:

```
@page
{ 
    size: auto;   /* auto is the initial value */ 

    /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */ 
    margin: 0.5in 0.5in 0.5in 0.5in;  
    @bottom-right
    {
    content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
   }
}
```

More specifically, the page count (@bottom-right) isn't showing up.  Am I supposed to put something else into the cshtml page to make it recognize the @page directive?

I have researched this, and gotten several ideas regarding the style sheet setup using @page, but haven't found anything regarding the cshtml setup needed.

Comment: Where has the `@bottom-right` come from? I've never seen that before.

Comment: If found that on 2 different stackoverflow answers:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109893/page-numbers-with-css-html

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050939/print-page-numbers-on-pages-when-printing-html