# Add text in margin

Tags: css, margin, footer

Is there any way to add some text like page number in margin?
I use below style for my print page:

```
@page {
    size: A4;
    margin-top: 1cm;
    margin-bottom: 1cm;
}
```

I have margin from bottom and top. I want to add some text and page number in margin. Any idea for it?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve...

Comment: I want to add footer inside margin-bottom

Comment: Hello look this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050939/print-page-numbers-on-pages-when-printing-html or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109893/page-numbers-with-css-html