# Page number in PDF print, only with HTML, CSS and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, pdf, printing

Does anyone know something about page number in @media print {}
I want something like "Page x of y" to display in my footer of every site in the PDF.

Is this even possible right now, without using a server side engine, and just code it in HTML, CSS and JavaScript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Page numbers with CSS/HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109893/page-numbers-with-css-html)

Comment: Tried that, but doesnt work.