# How to show href's page number after link when print

Tags: html, css

I want to make a book with a html page(http://www.akkit.org/info/gbatek.htm) and href makes it hard to find pages.
I just added code to show href after link but links are too long to see.

```
@media print {
  a[href]:after {
    content: " (" attr(href) ")";
  }
}
```

and I want to add page number of href like

DS I/O Maps (34/300 pages)
DS Memory Maps (42/300 pages)

Is there a way to show the page number of href's linked page?

Comment: Can you use `counter(page)` as mentioned on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109893/page-numbers-with-css-html?

Comment: when my code get into @page scope it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

`href` doesn't give any information about the page number ... What you can do instead is to add this information in a title attribute to the `a` tag or a custom `data` attribute and use it just like how you used the pseudo element with the `href`.

Comment: Then I should seperate pages arbitrarily and give a custom attribute?

Comment: can you clarify what you mean?